# object arrays inside knockout arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I don't know much about knockout but I am jumping into it.
Problem:
I am trying to retrieve a list (array) of objects inside a list of objects (array).

example: (just to make it very simple)

Teacher -> Students

1. Teacher #1

   - Student 1
   - Student 2
   - Student 3
2. Teacher #2

   - Student 1
   - Student 2
   - Student 3
3. Teacher #3

   - Student 1
   - Student 2
   - Student 3

So far I was able to display a list of all teachers but when displaying a list of students the last node (Teacher # 3) displays all the students from Teachers(#1 and #2 and #3); Teacher #1, #2 are blank.

```
var ViewModel = {
       Teachers: ko.observableArray([])
}

function LoadTeachers(....) //Here Teacher list is loaded successfully.>

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);


function teacher(T){
 this.TeacherID:ko.observable(T.TeacherID);
 this.TeacherName: ko.observable(T.TeacherName);

 this.StudentArray = ko.observableArray([]);

 function student(s){
    this.StudentID=ko.observable(s.StudentID);
    this.Name = ko.observable(s.s.Name);
 }

$.getJson('...');  // here is where Student array is loaded. 

}
```

then I would have in my view page:

```
foreach: Teacher  
foreach: Student
```

I am just using my knowledge of C# and applying to knockout.  I think the problem is declaring the Student Array inside the teacher object. Since student is a child for each teacher. This is what I would have done in C#.

Does anyone know if this coding is possible?  Hopefully it is!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post a proper javascript and html. Consider to create a fiddle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your code correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm ignoring the Knockout mapping plugin (which is good but not very well written) for a moment.  The reason is to allow you to see the solution simply.  So you had a couple of knockout oddities but mostly you were making a closure mistake.  The most important piece of the code is `var newTeacher = ...`.  The reason that's important is because you need to have that in the nested ajax closure.  So here's the code and the link to the working fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ViewModel = {
        Teachers: ko.observableArray([])
    };

    // some fake data to use instead of the ajax calls below, just so it works in fiddle
    var fakeTeacherData = [{TeacherID: 1, TeacherName: 'Dan'}, {TeacherID: 2, TeacherName: 'Marian'}];
    var fakeStudentData = [{StudentID: 1, Name: 'Student 1'}, {StudentID: 2, Name: 'Student 2'}];

    $.get('/echo/json', function(teacherData){
        // here you would use the data passed in of course
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(fakeTeacherData, function(T){
            var newTeacher = new teacher(T);
            ViewModel.Teachers.push(newTeacher);

            $.get('/echo/json', function(studentData){
                // here you would use the data passed in of course   
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(fakeStudentData, function(S){
                    newTeacher.Students.push(new student(S));
                });
            });
        });
    });
    ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
});

function teacher(T){
    this.TeacherID = ko.observable(T.TeacherID);
    this.TeacherName = ko.observable(T.TeacherName);
    this.Students = ko.observableArray([]);
}

function student(S){
    this.StudentID = ko.observable(S.StudentID);
    this.Name = ko.observable(S.Name);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kXQxA/

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys.. I appreciate your huge knowledge for helping me in this issue.  Both of your were very clever.  Although the project I am working is much more complex than the logic ( Teachers -> Students), I was able to use your help in solving my one week frustration.  Thank again to both of you...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display students by teacher, something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/LeCodeNinja/DnKAM/) should work.

```
Teacher = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id || 0);
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name || '');
    // See JSFiddle for mapping
    self.Students = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Students, StudentMapping);
    return self;
};

Student = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id || 0);
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name || '');
    return self;
};

StaffViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    // See JSFiddle for mapping
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, StaffMapping, self);
    return self;
};
```

I'm using the original Knockout mapping plugin, but you could use the viewmodel plugin.

If you'd like to display students and teachers in separate lists, then I would recommend not making the students observable properties of 'Teacher' and instead using some code in the ViewModel constructor to create the unique list of students.  The mapping plugin will still help out here, as the 'key' function will prevent dupes.